# DAX - Reference measure in calculated column?

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I have data like this

```
EmployeeID Value
1             7
2             6
3             5
4             3
```

I would like to create a DAX calculated column (or do I need a measure?) that gives me for each row, Value - AVG() of selected rows.
So if the AVG() of the above 4 rows is 5.25, I would get results like this

```
EmployeeID Value  Diff
1             7    1.75
2             6    0.75
3             5    -0.25
4             3    -1.75
```

Still learning DAX, I cannot figure out how to implement this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out with the help of some folks on MSDN forums.
This will only work as a measure because measures are selection aware while calculated columns are not.
The Average stored in a variable is critical. ALLSELECTED() gives you the current selection in a pivot table.
AVERAGEX does the row value - avg of selection.

Diff:=
Var ptAVG = CALCULATE(AVERAGE[Value],ALLSELECTED())

RETURN AVERAGEX(Employee, Value - ptAVG)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this with a calculated column. It's simply

```
Diff = TableName[Value] - AVERAGE(TableName[Value])
```

Note that this averages over all employees. If you want to average over only specific groups, then more work needs to be done.

Comment: This could also be a measured using CALCULATE and ALL for the average?

Comment: Thanks Alexis, like i said, the AVG only needs to be for the selected rows i.e. if a user is filtering on select rows, the avg needs to dynamically re-calculate based on the selection so i would appreciate a specific example

Comment: @SQLSeeker Can you give an example of what criteria you are filtering on?